# Sentence finishing by "interested", is Ok or should end by "in" or "by"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence

The sentence is:

> This demo application contains features you may be interested.

When I write "be interested by", Grammarly says that I should use "in".
Then, if I use "In", it says that the sentence shouldn't end by a preposition...

So, what is the correct way?

Comment: 'This demo application contains features you may be interested.' 100% wrong. 'This demo application contains features you may be interested in.' 100% acceptable (I've ignored the fraction of a percent of hyperprescriptive opinions). Look up 'ending sentence with preposition' in the search function (or 'Addisonian').

Comment: There _is_ no rule that forbids ending a sentence with a preposition. Sadly, though, there are many people that believe there is such a rule.

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase as follows: 'This demo application contains features which might be of interest to you.'

Comment: Do you mean that the OP's options "in" and "by" are both incorrect?

Comment: Or "...which may interest you."

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and use "in".  If Shakespeare could end a sentence with a preposition, then so can we!

Comment: Shakespeare used a great deal of SOV inversion. And nowadays weird senses of words. But you _know_ this is essentially a multidupe.

Answer (score 1):

INTERESTED is an adjective. We become" interested in something". Your sentence without the preposition IN becomes two separate clauses. We write the sentence the other way round to make it obvious.

- This demo application contains features (in which) you may be interested.

When we elide WHICH it becomes necessary to place IN at the rear with INTERSET it is related to. Here  my  foregoing sentence has been construed in the same way. Grammarly is correct in using IN.